# are there any processes that are not affected by SIGTERM?

Tags: c, linux, shell, signals

I have an assignment to write a code for a shell in C. one of the shell commands is "quit kill" where i have to send TERM signal to all child processes before shutting down the main process. 
if a child process doesn't shut down 5 second i have to send a KILL signal to kill it. 
now i already have written the code by i want to test it and i have no idea how, so do you guys have any idea of a process that ignores TERM signal?
here is the code i wrote for terminating one child process:

```
            kill(pid,SIGTERM);
            t = time(NULL);
            while(1){
                int state = waitpid(pid,&status,WNOHANG);
                if(state<0){
                    perror("Error ");
                    exit(0);
                }
                if(state == 0){
                    if((time(NULL)-t)>5){
                        printf("(5 sec passed) Sending SIGKILL… Done.\n");
                        kill(pid,SIGKILL);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    printf("Done.\n");
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 5):

This bash script ignores TERM:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap '' TERM
cat
```

Put it into a file and launch. Then try to kill it with TERM.

Answer (score 4):

Add a necessary include

```
#include <signal.h>
```

Declare a function that does nothing, for instance

```
void nothing(int x) {
    // nothing
}
```

Add at the beginning of the "protected" process code

```
signal(SIGTERM, nothing);
```

(you can also do `signal(SIGTERM, SIG_IGN);` without using the `nothing()` function -- from @rici comment)

That process will then catch the TERM signal that your main code sends, and execute the function `nothing()` that does nothing.

The [signal man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html).

Comment: You could just use `SIG_IGN` (see the same man page). And you cannot use `printf` in a signal handler, see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html

Comment: @Raeedmndow You can mark the answer as Accepted if you feel that's the one helping you the most.